# selenium webdriver-Xpath is not working for list

Tags: java, listview, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

i need to select the data from Excel file . Here i am using keyword driven framework. This is the HTML code

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
<div id="addDialog" class="hidden ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: auto; min-height: 30px; height: auto; max-height: 351.05px; overflow-y: auto;">
<div class="field-container">
<fieldset class="field-container">
<legend>Contracts:</legend>
<a class="select-all" href="#">Select All</a>
<a class="deselect-all" href="#">Deselect All</a>
<select id="addContract" class="searchable" multiple="multiple" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">
<option value="93370956">93370956</option>
<option value="93796167">93796167</option>
<option value="94203239">94203239</option>
</select>
<div id="ms-addContract" class="ms-container">
<div class="ms-selectable">
<input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="filter" autocomplete="off"/>
<ul class="ms-list" tabindex="-1">
<li id="86355560-selectable" class="ms-elem-selectable">
<span>93370956</span>
</li>
<li id="202890296-selectable" class="ms-elem-selectable">
<span>93796167</span>
</li>
<li id="938848030-selectable" class="ms-elem-selectable">
<span>94203239</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I am sending defined data from excel file. I tried some code but they are not selecting all the data from excel file at some point of time code is giving me exception for webElement not found.

TRY #1

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ms-list']/li/span[contains(text(),'"+testData+"')]"));
    for (WebElement option : options) {
      if(testData.equals(option.getText()))
        option.click();
```

TRY#2

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ms-list']/li/span[contains(text(),'"+testData+"')]"))).click();
If i have 10 data in list and i am reading them from my Excel file it above codes only select 3 or 4 and then gave me exception.

Then i tried with this one:

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ms-addContract']/div[1]/input"))).sendKeys(testData);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ms-addContract']/div[1]/input")).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.ARROW_DOWN,Keys.SPACE);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    //Clear the input text value.
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ms-addContract']/div[1]/input")).clear();
```

where it is sending data to filter textbox and selecting the popped up input. But it is taking time and if i don't put delay giving me timeout Exception.

Please help.

Comment: try refocusing `new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).perform();`

Comment: @redp tried with move to element though same exception no element found.

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ms-list']//span")));
  List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ms-list']//span[contains(.,'"+testData+"')]"));
  
   for (WebElement option : options) 
   {
      if(testData.equals(option.getText()))
        option.click();
   }
          
  } .. Tried with this code but it is selecting only one data